# Change background color in metapost

Tags: beamer, color, metapost

I have a metapost diagram using colour that when displayed in normal latex (with a white background) works well.  Now, I want to add the same diagram to a presentation done in Beamer (Warsaw theme) which has a blue background.  The diagram does not look good at all -- colour clash, too dark compared to the blue...

I have done this:

```
background:=white;
unfill (0,0)--(20u,0)--(20u,10u)--(0,10u)--cycle;
```

Which has the effect of drawing a white rectangle that then contains the diagram but it feel like a dirty hack.

How can I change the background of the diagram more elegantly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a receipe for drawing an image whose dimensions aren't known in advance on a background that scales to the image's final bounding box:

1. Draw the image.
2. Save the image in a picture variable.
3. Measure the picture's bounding box.
4. Draw the background.
5. Re-draw the original image on top of the background.

Here's an example followed by some random notes:

```
beginfig(1);
  %
  % Draw random picture.
  %
  pair p,q;
  for i = 1 upto 20:
    p := (uniformdeviate 200, uniformdeviate 200);
    q := (uniformdeviate 200, uniformdeviate 200);
    draw p--q withpen pencircle scaled 2 withcolor red;
  endfor
  %
  % Solution starts here.
  %
  % Save picture in variable pic for later reference.
  picture pic;
  pic := currentpicture;
  % Clear currentpicture to avoid outputting the picture twice.
  currentpicture := nullpicture;
  % Fill a rectangle with pic's bounding box dimensions (plus
  % bboxmargin) with desired background colour.
%  interim bboxmargin := 0;
  fill bbox pic withcolor blue;
  % Draw original picture on top of background.
  draw pic;
endfig;
end
```

Saving an image in a picture variable can either be done by storing `currentpicture` in a picture variable or via the `image` command (see the [MetaPost manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/metapost/base/manual/mpman.pdf) for more information).  If the `currentpicture` method is used, like in the example, make sure to clear `currentpicture` before drawing the background.  Otherwise the image is output twice, the first copy being hidden behind the background, bloating the output file.

The `bbox` command returns a rectangular path corresponding to the bounding box of the picture argument plus a small amount determined by the internal variable `bboxmargin` (2bp by default).

Internal variables can be modified locally to the current group using the `interim` statement.  That is, if you wrap an assignment to an internal variable in `begingroup ... endgroup;` the variable's value is restored after the group.  Note, `beginfig()` just starts a group that ends at the corresponding `endfig`.

Answer (score 3):

Drawing the rectangle with a color would be less weird, I think:

```
 fill (0,0)--(20u,0)--(20u,10u)--(0,10u)--cycle withcolor white;
```

it may be the background of the diagram, but if it is the first thing you draw that does not matter.

Comment: I was looking at something that would scale without me having to specify a bounding box in coordinates.  But your solution is more elegant than mine.  Thanks.